# Dynamically Populate Column Header in Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am generating a report using microsoft report viewer, I have to display the data for each day of selected month from dropdown in report, In this case how to change the column header dynamically with Date of month. Bcz with predefined dataset which we used to publish report I am not able to do like this, as in this case column headers name remains fixed.

For example, if user selected July then report should be like this--
Column Headers-- 07/01    07/02   07/03   07/04 .................07/31.

Comment: To clarify the question, each time you change the selected month from the pull down list, the dataset will be refreshed.  When the dataset is refreshed you want the column headers to be updated automatically.

Does the dataset contain any datetime or date data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your dataset has a value with the date-of-month for each of your results.

Create a single column group, showing the total in the details row, and have the header row show the date.

Below is a sample

with the following simple Dataset

```
DateOfMonth    Total
2015/03/04      44
2015/03/05      55
2015/03/06      66
2015/03/07      77
2015/03/07      11
```

The following setup of Column groups

[image]

Produces the following results
[image]

Then you just have to work out formatting, etc...